# TCP passthrough for HTTP connection with haproxy

Tags: haproxy, passthrough

I have done passthrough for HTTPS/SSL connections using SNI, but Id don't know if I can do the same for HTTP using host header? is there any way I can use passthrough (tcp mode) in stead of reverse-proxy (http mode) for http connections?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, simply create a TCP listener forwarding to your servers. Of course in that case it becomes a layer 4 load balancer and you will not be able to use any layer 7 functions like path and host based routing.

Also make sure to use stickiness if your servers cannot share session information.

```
listen my_listener
    bind *:80
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    balance leastconn
    server server1 1.2.3.4:80
    server server2 2.3.4.5:80
```

For SSL, just use 443.

Comment: The problem is that I will be able only to listen to one domain. I guess that for HTTP you cannot use tcp mode if you want to act based on host name.

Comment: @jlanza Well, yes. A layer 4 load balancer is not aware of anything on higher layers. Http is a layer 7 protocol. As such, of you want to make decisions based on anything happening in layer 7, such as host, path, headers, etc., you need a layer 7 load balancer.